# C# Interop Excel format like Excel's format as table

Tags: c#, formatting, excel-interop

I'm exporting a table from `SQLite` to `Excel` (2010) in `C#`. It works fine.  I'm using the `Excel.Range.set_Value()` method.

How can I format an `Excel.Range` like `Excel's` format (like a table) would?

Comment: As in applying one of the built in Table Styles of Excel 2010?  You could set the TableStyle property of your Range to TableStyleMedium1 or any of the built in Table Styles.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To expand upon my comment and add to D Stanley.

```
Range range = ws.get_Range("A1:D5");
wrksheet.ListObjects.AddEx(XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange, range, missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlNo, missing).Name = "MyTableStyle";
wrksheet.ListObjects.get_Item("MyTableStyle").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium1";
```

Comment: Thank you! I have used old version of Interop!

Comment: David Yenglin: this works amazingly!, just one problem i'm having regarding it. All of my coulmns original name automatically change to column1, column2, coulmn3, etc ....... do you know how to keep the original coulmn names?

Comment: oki, so i got around this problem by changing a bit of your code, XlYesNoGuess.xlNo -> XlYesNoGuess.xlYes

Answer (score 2):

This example selects a rectangular range of every cell in the active sheet. Also, it uses indexed parameters of Range to get the range points. Furthermore, AddEx() (and most methods in  Interop.Excel) uses default parameters so you don't have to use System.Reflection.Missing.

```
// define points for selecting a range
// point 1 is the top, leftmost cell
Excel.Range oRng1 = oSheet.Range["A1"];
// point two is the bottom, rightmost cell
Excel.Range oRng2 = oSheet.Range["A1"].End[Excel.XlDirection.xlToRight]
    .End[Excel.XlDirection.xlDown];

// define the actual range we want to select
oRng = oSheet.Range[oRng1, oRng2];
oRng.Select(); // and select it

// add the range to a formatted table
oRng.Worksheet.ListObjects.AddEx(
    SourceType: Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange,
    Source: oRng,
    XlListObjectHasHeaders: Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's the VBA that does it:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add xlSrcRange, Range("$J$10:$N$12"), , xlYes
```

Shouldn't be too hard to translate into an automation call.  You can [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.listobjects.add%28v=office.14%29.aspx) as well.